# Issues with https to https redirect in Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, https, redirect

I want the following redirects to happen:

http://www.example.org -> https://example.org [working]

https://www.example.org -> https://example.org [not working]

As you can see when using "https" it's not redirecting to https://example.org but just stays at https://www.example.org

My www.conf (for www.example.org):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.org

    Redirect / https://example.org

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /srv/www

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.org

    Redirect / https://example.org

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /srv/www

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www_ssl_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www_ssl_access.log combined

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/certbot.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

My main.conf (for example.org):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.org

    Redirect / https://example.org

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/main_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/main_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.org

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/main_ssl_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/main_ssl_access.log combined

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/certbot.conf
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

Comment: Do you have a VirtualHost with example.org in your config?

Comment: Sorry for my edit, badly read your question, Gerald was faster than me to fix

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Yes, please check the op, I included it now.

Comment: Are you testing with a web browser or using a command line utility instead? Most **browsers cache permanent redirects** as well as  [**HTTP Strict Transport Security**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) headers which requires using a  new incognito/anonymous browser session to test each change in the configuration that you make. - On a side note, if you're only redirecting and not serving any content you don't need to create or set a DocumentRoot in the VirtualHost entry

Comment: @HBruijn Yes `DocumentRoot` is not needed if I am just only redirecting. Needed to add it when trying to get a SSL certificate from `certbot`. I am testing on a web browser in incognito mode. And I am reopening the browser every time. Learnt my lessons when I messed with HSTS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this (not a complete config, just showing the concept):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.org
    ServerAlias www.example.org

    Redirect Permanent / https://example.org
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.org
    ServerAlias www.example.org

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.org
    RewriteRule (.*) https://example.org$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

The idea here is one VirtualHost per port, not per domain.  www.DOMAIN and DOMAIN is almost the same.  So any request that comes on port 80, it redirects to https on port 443. Any request that comes to port 443 will redirect to "itself", removing the www if needed.

Combining the VirtualHost via ServerAlias is clean and simplifies your configuration.

You need to add certificates, logs, ...  as I said, this is not production ready!

Comment: I disabled `www.conf` and did as shown in your answer. Every url is redirecting to `https://www.example.org/` making it even worse. I want the `www` subdomain gone.

Comment: Oups, my bad I answered the reverse.  I modified my answer.

Comment: This is totally working! :)